# i am trying to connect firebase cloud messaging to android app. app is not loading the error "Could not find com.google.firbase:firebase-core:17.0.1."

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
dependencies {
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
implementation "com.google.firbase:firebase-core:17.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1"
// implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.2.0')
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
//noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
}

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
}

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
}

if (enableHermes) {
    def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
    debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
    releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
} else {
    implementation jscFlavor
}
```

}

want to connect firebase cloud messaging and i got the error Could not find com.google.firbase:firebase-core:17.0.1. when i run the android app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you forgot the letter `e` for `firbase`. Replace "com.google.firbase:firebase-core:17.0.1" with "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1".

I believe that the `firebase-core` has been removed in React Native Firebase, see about the [installation of Cloud Messaging](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#installation) on documentation, it doesn't need the `firebase-core` and `firebase-messaging`.